# Yosemite Finder Column View Modified Timestamp

Tags: finder, macos, system-settings

Upon updating to Yosemite, My finder column view preview window displays the Modified and Last Opened options as "Today" or "Yesterday" etc. I need to see *what time* yesterday in the column view without the extra step of having to Get File Info. Is there a way to get an actual timestamp to display in the column view? I see no option in settings for this.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that enlarging the preview area allows room for the timestamp to show.

Answer (score 0):

If you select "Show View Options" in the Finder (`View -> Show View Options` or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) and look towards the bottom, there is an option `Use relative dates`. Uncheck this.